# Looking for the Type details for page_stories_by_story_type & page_consumptions_by_consumption_type

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page, facebook-insights

We are pulling page stats for page_stories_by_story_type & page_consumptions_by_consumption_type. I am looking for some confirmation and insight for the below Types.

We believe we have been able to determine a few of these but some we are not sure if they are included or not.

page_stories_by_story_type will return...

- like a page = fan
- post on the page wall = user post
- like a post = user post
- comment on a post = page post
- share a post = user post
- answer a question = question
- RSVP to a page’s event = ????
- mention the page in a post = mention
- tag the page in a photo = mention
- check in at a place = checkin
- share a check-in deal = ????
- like a check-in deal = ????
- write a recommendation = ?? we do not believe this is included ??

page_consumptions_by_consumption_type...

- Click on Page Name = other
- Click on Link in the “Status” portion of message = other
- Click on Link in the “Link” portion of message = link
- Click on Time Stamp = other
- Click on App Name = ????other????
- Click on # of Likes = other
- Click on Number of Shares = ????other????

Comment: This likes something good to add to fbdevwiki.com as this is something that several people would probably find useful and really should be documented.

Comment: I have shared this with simoncross from fb see if he can help

Answer (score 1):

At time of writing, the full list of available story types is:

- page post
- tag
- mention
- checkin
- user post
- deal
- fan
- comment
- purchase
- paid
- link
- question
- coupon
- other

The full list of available consumption types is:

- link clicks
- other clicks
- photo view
- video play
- other

For each, the mapping should be perfectly clear. Any remaining activities will default to 'other' in both cases.